# I need a resource for basic convex optimization algorithms.

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization

I'm trying to decide whether or not a certain CS problem can be solved in polynomial time.  I've got it reduced down to a basic convex optimization problem, but I can't for the life of me find a good resource that tells me when convex optimization problems are in P.

I'd like some sort of reference that has:

- A list of common optimization algorithms
- The restrictions on the problem that must be satisfied in order to use each of these algorithms
- The runtime of the algorithms, in terms of $\epsilon$ (the difference between the true optimal point and the point that was returned by the algorithm).

I don't particularly need an in-depth description of the inner workings of these algorithms.  I just want to know what's out there.

Thank you!